# Why is this category failing to display the theme properly?

Tags: category, theme, ce-1.7.0.2

Please see this link http://www.yolli.com/packaging
It is the ONLY category on our store which does not display correctly.

I have checked this category's settings and compared them to the other categories, nothing is missing or incorrect.

It has me stumped, hence this post. I hope one of you guys can point me in the right direction. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: http://www.yolli.com/?___SID=Upackaging seems to display OK. Also, if you have a look on the server in /var/report you'll see some files that will contain details of the error. Maybe post the details of 187114974802 if you need more help

Comment: This is what I see https://ibb.co/jAmVkv which is not correct when compared to the other pages

Comment: Hi @lhuikneton please look into these points http://prntscr.com/fhcra5

Comment: @lhuikneton I was saying that http://yolli.com/?___SID=Upackaging displays fine but http://www.yolli.com/packaging doesn't so the clue is in the lack of the querystring. FTP to your server and look in /var/report/187114974802  for details of what is happening

Comment: the URL you have provided goes to the homepage.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/n3aRMnby here is the contents of the report

Comment: @jscar 
 
pastebin.com/n3aRMnby here is the contents of the report

Comment: In the Packing source html there is <[!--{gomage_procart/config_gomage.procart.config}--]> (it's also in Decoration html source)
It's not in Bakery html and that is a CMS page not a category page. Maybe that helps you track down the error?

Comment: @jscar thank you very much for taking a look. I will look into your findings further tomorrow and hopefully be able to figure out the cause of the problem.

Comment: @jscar could you clarify what you mean by " that is a CMS page not a category page."

Comment: OK, I've just looked back at your site and I thought that yesterday I had seen a class attribute of "cms-xxxx" on the body element in one of the category pages. Seems I was mistaken.Sorry for the wrong lead :(

Comment: @jscar okay thanks. So do you have any other ideas?

Comment: This <[!--{gomage_procart/config_gomage.procart.config}--]> is getting written out in the html of the Packaging page. It might be worth contacting GoMage to see if they can help you track down what's happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that two of the configurable products had no associated products. So when the theme ran PHP to fetch the lowest price of the associated products and found none, it threw an error which prevented the rest of the page from loading.